# why the cowboy as httpclient can't start inets

Tags: cowboy, inets

I want to send http post out from cowboy by using the otp's `httpc:request/4;`

the application:start(inets) returns an error:

> error,{"no such file or directory","inets.app"}

how can i start the inets??

Answer (score 0):

from https://github.com/ninenines/cowboy/issues/1040#issuecomment-254970067

"try adding LOCAL_DEPS = inets to your Makefile and do make run again."

This worked for me.